# Rails 4: ajax call to controller action returning 404 not found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok Im like 1 hour trying to figure this out...

I have this action in my oferts_controller.rb

```
    def update_categories
     @categories = Category.children_of(Category.find(params[:categories]))
     respond_to do |format|
      format.js
     end
    end
```

This is what I have in routes.rb

```
get 'oferts/update_categories', as: 'update_categories'
```

This is what I have in my ajax call

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#categories_parents_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_categories',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        categories: $("#categories_parents_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

it is suposed that the update_categories action responds as a JavaScript, which is in app/views/oferts/update_categories.js.coffee

```
$("#categories_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @categories)) %>")
```

well after I try to execute the ajax I get this in the logs

```
Started GET "/oferts/update_categories?categories=3&_=1427927753744" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-01 17:36:01 -0500
Processing by OfertsController#update_categories as JS
  Parameters: {"categories"=>"3", "_"=>"1427927753744"}
  Rendered public/404.html (0.6ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 38ms (Views: 36.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Well if you see it is not even entering to the controller action, I tried adding `puts` inside the update_categories `def` in the controller but those are not printed in the logs. is this routing problem?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: It does look like a routing problem. In your ajax call, try using the path 'oferts/update_categories' instead.

Comment: I did and it says 'oferts/oferts/update_categories' is not defined =( what else can I do T_T

Comment: Would you post your routes file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have once got this problem

finally, I find that the problem is in the filter

Could you have any filer in your controller and would you like post it for help?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, you turned on a light in my brain, yea I had the 
before_filter :authenticate_user! and  load_and_authorize_resource of cancancan, I just added except: array my update_categories action. Thank you again, The rail's error was not very descriptive...

Comment: @SsouLlesS Happy to help you fixed this problem. And this is my first best anwser on SO , thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists in not allowing such ajax methods in controller to pass even without any validation or authentication. You need to take a look in your controller either **oferts_controller.rb or application_controller.rb**. There must be some **before_filter** that is instead redirecting it to 404.

Thanks